# php str_replace is wrote by what string matching algorithms?

Tags: php, string, algorithm, highlight, matching

Today I just need to know which string matching algorithms `str_replace` uses. I just analysed the php source code, this function is in `ext\standard\string.c`. I just found out `php_char_to_str_ex`. Who can tell me which algorithms this function is written in? (which algorithms achieve `str_replace` this function ) .

And I just want to realize a highlight program which used Sunday algorithms (very quick algorithms and they say only this algorithms )

So I think this function `str_replace` maybe fits my goals, so I just analysed it ,but my C is so poor, so help me please guys.

Comment: you want name of the algorithm? what if algorithm used doesn't have any specific name?

Comment: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/b9185a45443bda94898389a724f1c44ae1d09234/ext/standard/string.c#L3945

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: it's just a simple brute-force search.

The `str_replace` function is really just a forwarder to `php_str_replace_common`. And for the simple case where the subject is not an array, that in turn calls `php_str_replace_in_subject`. And again, when the search parameter is just a string, and it's more than 1 character, that calls `php_str_to_str_ex`.

Looking at the `php_str_to_str_ex` implementation, there are various special cases that are handled.

1. If the the search string and the replacement string are the same length, it make the memory handling easier because you know the result string is going to be the same size and the source string.
2. If the search string is longer than the source string, you know it's never going to find anything so you can simply return the source string unchanged.
3. If the search string length is identical to the source string length, then it's just a straight comparison.

But for the most part, it comes down to repeatedly calling `php_memnstr` to find the next match, and replacing that match with `memcpy`.

As for the `php_memnstr` implementation, that just calls C's `memchr` repeatedly to try and match the first character of the search string, and then `memcmp` to see if the rest of the string matches.

There's no fancy preprocessing of the search string to optimise repeated searches. It is just a straightforward brute-force search.

I should add, that even when the subject is an array, and there would be an advantage to preprocessing the search string, the code doesn't do anything different. It just calls `php_str_replace_in_subject` for each string in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as of now (March 2015) I see in the PHP source code that `str_replace()` function relies on Sunday string matching algorithm.

`str_replace()` function uses `zend_memnstr_ex_pre()` and `zend_memnstr_ex()` functions (from `zend_operators.c` file) that use [Sunday algorithm](http://www.iti.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/pattern/sundayen.htm).